# How to inherit few properties from base class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have come across a scenario where I have to inherit only few properties from base class and leave other properties as it is.

So for example

```
class A
{
    public string A1
    public string A2
}

class B : A
{
    public string A3;
    public string B1;
}
```

Now I should be able to use properties like B.A1,B.B1 and B.A3, But I don't want A2 to be available in class B***. Remember I don't want to use private*** , I have to keep it public because its a mongo entity document and need to be stored in mongo DB

**Basically I am trying to share few common properties between two entities using inheritance.**

Comment: make it private which you don't want to be visible in child

Comment: @EhsanSajjad its a entity for mongo document, so can't make it private otherwise field will not get saved in mongo DB.

Comment: Be clear about properties vs fields, also in pseudo code.

Comment: @bommelding that's true, but then I have nested class inside it, which makes it complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if we don't want property `A2` to be accessible from derived class `B` we 
(most likely) shouldn't use inheritance in the first place. 
We could use aggregation instead:

```
class A
{
    public string A1 { get; set; }
    public string A2 { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public string A1 { get; set; }
    public string A3 { get; set; }
    public string B1 { get; set; }

    public B(A instance)
    {
       this.A1 = instance.A1;
    }
}
```

Comment: that's what worked for me now. I think C# team can think of feature where you can just ignore few properties from inheritance.

Comment: @KrunalParmar - no the C# team will never do that. It would break C# and OO.

Answer (score 3):

Refactor.

```
class AA
{
    public string A1 { get; set; }
}

class A : AA
{
    public string A2 { get; set; }
}

class B : AA
{
    public string A3  { get; set; }
    public string B1  { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I must have misunderstood the question, since class `B` still inherits `A1` property from `AA`.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide public variables by shadowing them with private ones.

```
class Base {
    public string P1 { get; set; }
    public string P2 { get; set; }
}

class Limited: Base {
    new private string P1 { get; set; }
    // P2 will be inherited as public, P1 will be hidden to the user
}
```

Although I would take a step back and consider encapsulation instead of inheritance. This hide-and-seek with property attributes smells.

Comment: Hiding members is something that may be forced on you by a base class or interface but you should never consider it a valid modeling tool. Always avoid it.